How to deploy Databricks Unity Catalog table with CI/CD
Does anyone know how to deploy Databricks schema changes with Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline?
I have created a table in Dev database (in Databricks Unity Catalog) and I want to deploy it to Prod Database with Azure DevOps same way I deploy Notebooks.
I know in Snowflake it is done with "schemachange", and in SQL Server its done with a "dacpac" thing.
What's the equivalent for Databricks?
Theres plenty info on how to deploy Notebooks but can't find anything on deploying Database objects.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
